# Continue sequence mediation after timeout in call mediator

Tags: wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-esb

Endpoints can have three timeout configurations. Never timeout, discard, or fault. I desperately need to continue the flow after a timeout. Is there a way to achieve this? Fault handler (onError sequence) is not a desired solution for this issue. Imagine orchestration with eight call mediators, I would have to create eight sequences and set each other as fault. This would very quickly bloat carbon apps, make code unreadable and increase deployment time.

Comment: Does the rest of the mediation depends on the response of the endpoint call ?

Comment: Yes and no. Real-life example, we use custom template, which logs request to database, call target endpoint, logs response to database. This is an abstraction layer, basically our custom framework. Now we have a several usecases, where we want to call one system, and if that fails no matter how, call a different system. It is basically a filter, where we check data, and if no data found, call second system with different request. Issue is, that timeout stops mediation, clears Continuation Stack and calls Fault Handler. I need to call mediator to not execute fault sequence, but continue.

Comment: From example above, it's obvious why we cannot use onError sequence. We can set only one onError sequence in the abstraction template, but every usecase needs to react differently, they cannot share this fault sequence.

Answer (score 0):

Basically,at any given time, the state of the endpoint can be one of the following.

1. Active
2. Timeout
3. Suspend
4. OFF

When an endpoint is in the "Timeout" state, it will continue to attempt to receive messages until one message succeeds or the maximum retry setting has been reached. If the maximum is reached at which point the endpoint is marked as "Suspended." If one message succeeds, the endpoint is marked as "Active."

If you need to continue the mediation flow when you get an endpoint timeout as per the endpoint timeout configuration, you can use the **fault** option in responseAction.

Then, whenever the endpoint is timeout, the fault sequence (custom fault sequence if you have defined it already, otherwise the default fault sequence) will be hit. If you need to continue the mediation flow and as per the existing implementation, you can define the required mediation logic in a custom sequence and call that sequence in the fault sequence as follows.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<sequence name="customFaultSequence" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <!-- Log the message at the full log level with the ERROR_MESSAGE and the ERROR_CODE-->
    <log level="full">
         <property name="MESSAGE" value="Executing default 'fault' sequence"/>
         <property expression="get-property('ERROR_CODE')" name="ERROR_CODE" xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd"/>
         <property expression="get-property('ERROR_MESSAGE')" name="ERROR_MESSAGE" xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd"/>
    </log>
    <sequence key="afterTimeoutEndpointSequence"/>
</sequence>
```

Sample proxy service:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="TestProxy" startOnLoad="true" statistics="disable" trace="disable"    transports="http,https">
   <target faultSequence="customFaultSequence">
      <inSequence>
               <endpoint>
                  <address uri="http://run.mocky.io/v3/51c11e65-55a7-47e5-ba38-1d86e8e5d7ea?mocky-delay=45000ms">
                     <timeout>
                        <duration>2</duration>
                        <responseAction>fault</responseAction>
                     </timeout>
                  </address>
               </endpoint>
           <respond/>
      </inSequence>
   <description/>
</proxy>
```

Comment: As I said, fault handler (which is this case) is not a feasible solution. I need to continue mediaton after call mediator in the same sequence, not in different sequence. I don't want to use fault responseAction and basically call onError sequence, that's what we've been doing for a year and it starts to get horribly in a way of clean code.

Comment: @TomášMrázek, according to the current architecture you have to follow the above approach to achieve your requirement.